# Integrals involving Bose-functions (Computational)

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, bosons, self-energy

In short, I'm looking for some advice/literature how to deal numerically with Bose function.

My physical problem is to calculate a coupled set of Self-energies, thermal loop integrals, self consistently. These integrals involve Bose and Boltzman distributions.

There is some literature for the Anderson model (in NCA) dealing with a similar problem, where instead of Bose function, Fermi function appear.
Here due to the exponential growth of the Boltzman factor in the negative frequency, the involved Greens-function/Spectral-functions must vanish exponentially there. This numerical problem can be simplified by scaling all Spectral-function and Self-energies by the Fermi function (of minus the argument).

When working now with Bose functions the 1/x divergence at zeros is also present.

I would be glad for some advice or literature suggestion, on how numerical calculation involving Bose distributions are done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great paper [On the Relativistic Bose-Einstein Integrals](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.525239) by Weldon and Haber which I have found useful in the past. It focuses on asymptotic expansions of generic Bose-Einstein integrals in the high-$T$ and low-$T$ limits, but maybe it will be useful for you.